# Retrieving Array of object from a Resultset scala

Tags: scala, hive, hiveql

Trying to retrieve Array object from a hive JDBC `ResultSet` using `resultSet.getArray("variables")` but received error as `Java.sql.SQLException: Method Not Supported`

Code:

```
case class Variables(val variable:String, val type:String, val value:String)
case class Updates(val title:String, val variables:Array[Variables])

val resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from updates")

val collection = new Iterator[Updates]{
def hasNext = resultSet.next()
def next = Updates(resultSet.getString("title"),resultSet.getArray("variables").getArray.asInstanceOf[Array[Variables]])
}.toStream
```

Error:

`Java.sql.SQLException: Method Not Supported at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.getArray(HiveBaseResultSet.java:117)`

Also please suggest if there is any direct method to cast `resultSet` objects to `case class Updates` without this converions.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `.getObject` function?

```
getObject(int columnIndex, Class<T> type) or
getObject(String columnLabel, Class<T> type)
```

Comment: This error indicates that `Array[Variables]` is not supported so
you can try use `play.api.libs.json._` then try create implicit conversion to you case class to do the conversion.

Comment: Same Error Method not Supported

Comment: `resultSet.getArray("variables")` did you try to check if this code runs ?

Comment: So means that the method you are using is not supported by the version you are using or maybe deprecated bro. Kindly refer the from official Docs of your version used.

Comment: Apparently, getObject will ultimately throw an Exception here.                          Code: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/6d4b19b5534781e21d30b5c67889f64401c051ed/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveBaseResultSet.java#L459

Comment: @james.bondu, is there any fix or work around for this ?